# Play Framework 2 Optional parameter in routes

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm having a small issue with Play's routes file. I have the following (my controller is written in Java):

```
GET    /api/:domain/shop/shopBuyItems    @controller.MyController.myMethod(optionalLong: Option[Long])
```

However, when I do this, I get the following error:

```
 found   : scala.Option[scala.Long]
 required: play.libs.F.Option[java.lang.Long]]
```

This is the workaround I currently have, but of course this gets ugly really fast:

```
GET    /api/:domain/shop/shopBuyItems    @controller.MyController.myMethod(optionalLong: play.libs.F.Option[java.lang.Long])
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Thanks :) !

Comment: For Java solution is as simple as in the other answer: `GET  /foo  controller.Foo.index(id: java.lang.Long ?= null)` see the docs: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaRouting

Comment: Thanks for finding the duplicate. It's rather unfortunate that we need to specify the full qualified names to use Java types.

Comment: Cause it's parsed by Scala initially and by default considers Scala types, fortunately this rule is easy to remember. ;)